# two php files call one php and execute different functions

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access one PHP file from two PHP files.

`insert.php` file is used to insert values into a certain table and then `modify.php` file is used to modify the values of the table.

I want to write two functions in `database.php` -- one for inserting and another for modifying. And I want to include this file into `insert.php` and `modify.php

I just want to execute only insert function from `database.php` and `insert.php` page call and execute only the modify function from `database.php` when `modify.php` page is called.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Why not? include file with function declarations and call the functions you need.

Comment: show the code of database.php

Comment: `if($insert) { include 'insert.php'; }` .....

Comment: i meant to say that, database.php has 2 functions like insert_values() and modify_values()

i have a html page used to insert values and modify values.
when i am trying to insert values in a table the insert.php file will call and/or if i am trying to modify the values of table then modify.php will call. i include database.php file in both insert.php and modify.php
now i have to execute only insert_values() function from database.php when insert.php file call. as well as for modify.php file also... please explain the solution sir. thanks in advance.

Comment: check my answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18845503/1357033

Comment: yeah, just now i checked. Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**database.php**

```
<?php
function insert_fn()
{
//write insert code here
echo "inserted"; //just for demo.
}
function modify_fn()
{
//write modifycode here
echo "modified."; //just for demo.
}
?>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
include("database.php");
insert_fn();
?>
```

**modify.php**

```
<?php
include("database.php");
modify_fn();
?>
```

Comment: Ok sir. after i execute the file. if it will give right output then i will. thank you.

Comment: i have 2 form files names form1.php and form2.php . both file has Submit button. when i click on Submit button .... both files will call only one file named execute.php . i write code like 
form1.php :  <form action="execute.php" .......></form>
form2.php :  <form action="execute.php" .......></form>

execute.php have insert() delete() methods. when one form1.php submitted then insert() method would be execute and as well as when form2.php submitted then delete90 method would be call.
according to your above answer how can i write code in <form action="??????????">
please give me the solution.

Comment: you can set name for each submit button. and in execute.php, check the name of submit button and do the rest. got it?

Comment: yes sir. but the question is . i use name ="submit" and value ="submit" in both forms. then let me know how can i get different methods when different forms are submitted??

Comment: please change name or value and check that in execute.php or place any hidden field in form and check

Answer (score 0):

You can create your database.php file with the two functions you mentioned: `function update()` and `function insert()`.

You then use the php `include` to include the database.php file into your other two files, like this:

insert.php

```
include_once('database.php');
insert(your data comes here);
```

modify.php

```
include_once('database.php');
update(your data comes here);
```

You should make a Database Layer where you have your Model and use an instance of the Class for this. You then include your database.php into your other scripts and instantiate your db object and call your method. Something like this:

database.php

```
class MyDatabaseThingy 
{
    /* rest of your code */
    public function update(data) {your code here}
    public function insert(data) {your code here}
    /* rest of your code */
}
```

insert.php

```
include_once(database.php);
$dbObj = new MyDatabaseThingy();
/* make sure you have the connection and so on */
$dbObj->insert(your data);
```

modify.php

```
include_once(database.php);
$dbObj = new MyDatabaseThingy();
/* make sure you have the connection and so on */
$dbObj->update(your data);
```